# make image rotate by following the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, offset

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = $('#player');
    //Checks to see which key is pressed down

    $(window).on('mousemove', function (e) {

      //Current position
      var p1 = {
        x: player.offsetLeft,
        y: player.offsetTop
      };

      //Future position
      var p2 = {
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
      };

      //Angle between them in degrees
      var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;

      if(angleDeg >= 360){
        angleDeg -= 360;
      }


        player.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angleDeg + 'deg)');
    });
});
```

Nothing happens. If I write something like:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#player").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

The image follows the mouse. I just want to make it rotate.

[**Full fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/SEGaT/1/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Offset

To access those offsetLeft and offsetTop properties in jQuery, you should use player.offset().top and player.offset().left. Here are the [jQuery docs for the offset function.](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) Just trying to access the offsetLeft or offsetTop property of that object was producing undefined, which was making your angle calculations fail.

### Image Orientation

Once you fix that, the car won't be pointing in the right direction (it's off by 90 degrees). You could either change the rotation of the image file, or you could just insert that adjustment into the angle calculation function.

Comment: I was really hoping jsfiddle would let me fork the code in time for an edit, but it's under heavy load apparently. Here it is at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uHiREFe/1/watch?html,css,js,output

Comment: thanks man! But when it was a bit weird, because when my code was based on onmousedown with the same calculations, offsetleft and top worked..

Comment: The reason it worked is because you were referencing the event, not the jQuery object, I think.